# I am getting an error SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Tags: pandas, dataframe

These are the two paths

```
market_overview_preprocessed_path='C://Users/anubhav/Downloads/a.xlsx'
crop_amiga_mapping_path='C://Users/anubhav/Downloads/b.xlsx'
```

then i start writing my code

```
input_dfs_names=[str(market_overview_preprocessed_path),str(crop_amiga_mapping_path)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for files in input_dfs_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(files)
```

i am getting an error as shown in fig
[image]

Comment: Did you copy and paste this code from somewhere? This usually means you have an invalid or non-printing character somewhere in your code. Try deleting the spaces in front of `df = pd.read_parquet(files)` and replacing them with tabs from your keyboard.

Comment: Can you pls look now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the error it was due to indendation error.

Answer (score 0):

I think your path definitions are wrong. Check if this works:

```
market_overview_preprocessed_path='C:\\Users\\anubhav\\Downloads\\a.xlsx'
crop_amiga_mapping_path='C:\\Users\\anubhav\\Downloads\\b.xlsx'
input_dfs_names=[market_overview_preprocessed_path, crop_amiga_mapping_path]

# rest of your code here...
```

alternatively:

```
market_overview_preprocessed_path=r'C://Users/anubhav/Downloads/a.xlsx'
crop_amiga_mapping_path=r'C://Users/anubhav/Downloads/b.xlsx'

# Rest of your code
```